# Posting large JSON to MVC action method : The length of the string exceeds the value

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post big json in mvc action method.
which result in error

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property. Parameter name: input

I know there're many post on SO and google, i've tried many solution but none of them worked for me:

What I've tried:
Updated **Web.Config**

Updated this statement in **system.web**

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="1073741824"  />
```

and following line in Systerm.webserver

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

after adding above lines it worked for me in local, but after updating same value on server its not working, it throws above error.

**Update**

```
IIS Version 7.5
```

Comment: Which version of iis is your server running?

Comment: @DaiBok IIS version 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the following to your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="{required length of json in bytes}" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

The max value is 2147483647 and the default is 102400 (100kb) which may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following ways:

1. Send data as object not like `url` parameters in ajax call like below.

   ```
         $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   data: JSON.stringify(data),
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data) {

                   },
                   error: function (a, b, c) { console.log(a); }
               });
   ```
2. You can see my [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719417/8375010).