# Solution: The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property for POST action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've following code in MVC. In my POST action `params` will have huge data. So, I changed `web.config` accordingly but, I'm getting **ERROR**. Actual problem is controller is not even hitting when POST is called.

`I tried Following ways`

1. Override JsonResult
2. followed [Link](https://forums.asp.net/post/4739027.aspx). Here i couldn't see data which is sent from script. I'm getting **NULL** in `base64`.

**controller.cs**

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public bool postImage(string base64)
    {
       return true;
    }
```

**web.config**

```
 <system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:21923/communities/postImage?base64=',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById('test').click();
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
  }
})
```

> Error

**Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.\r\nParameter name: input**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory.cs`and write following code:

```
public sealed class JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
  public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
 {
    if (controllerContext == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");

    if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return null;

    var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
    var bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText) ? null : new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(bodyText, new ExpandoObjectConverter()) , CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 }
}
```

and add following two lines in `Global.asax.cs` in `Application_Start()`

```
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().FirstOrDefault());
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory());
```

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9512095/8375010)

Thanks to [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) !!

**If above code fails: Follow [This](https://forums.asp.net/post/4739027.aspx) might helps a lot**

Thanks to [dkinchen](https://forums.asp.net/members/dkinchen.aspx) !!